# Arrendondamento de número em Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto para cálculo de desgaste de determinadas peças de um veículo. Porém ainda sou novo na linguagem Python.

Meu problema, por exemplo, é o seguinte:

O litro do combustível custa R$ 5,83, que por sua vez faz com que meu veículo percorra 22 km. Logo, eu tenho um gasto de R$ 0,265 por quilômetro rodado.

Se eu usar a função `ceil`, esse valor final seria arrendondado para R$1,00. Sendo que o interessante seria ser arredondado para R$ 0,27.

Que função ou operação é mais indicada nesse caso?

Comment: Utilize a função round(), pesquise sobre ela na documentação.

Answer (score 6):

**sugestão 1**

uma boa prática nesses casos, se a precisão não for muito crítica é deixar o Python armazenar o valor das contas como forem feitas, sem se preocupar com esse valor - e, apenas na hora de *apresentar* o  valor aos usuários você arredonda com o número de casas decimais desejados.

Fazendo assim, se você tem várias operações a realizar com alguns números, o Python armazena todos os resultados intermediários na precisão máxima permitida por [números em ponto flutuante de 64 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). Isso faz com que erros que poderiam ser introduzidos nas suas contas por um arredondamento antes da hora sejam cancelados no final.

Para a representação, o que você tem que ter em mente é o seguinte: o número fica numa variável do Python, e, em algum ponto, o seu programa vai gerar a saída para o usuário final. Não importa se essa saída é em um trecho de HTML, se for uma aplicação Web, ser mostrado num print no terminal, ser mostrado num widget na tela, ser exportado num arquivo tipo CSV, ou ser gravado num banco de dados: é só nesse momento que a precisão menor importa. E em todos os casos acima, e mais alguns, o número é serializado como uma string de dígitos decimais. (A única exceção é o banco de dados, se ele for apenas ser consumido pela sua proria aplicação de volta, pode deixar o número sem arredondamento no banco também).

Então, você pode usar a sintaxe de formatação de strings, com as novas f-strings do Python 3.6, para especificar o número exato de casas decimais desejadas, e a linguagem arredonda pra você - [inclusive cuidando dos casos de números quebrados por que não podem ser representados corretamente na base binária](https://floating-point-gui.de/) - que é o formato nativo dos números em ponto flutuante.

Por exemplo, no seu caso, com 
preco_por_litro = 5.83
km_rodados = 22
litros_abastecidos = 1
preco_por_km = preco_por_litro * litros_abastecidos / km_rodados

Se você imprimir o "preco_por_km" com `print(preco_por_km)`, chega no `0.265` - 
mas se você usar a formatação de strings, pode fazer:

```
print(f"Preço por km: R${preco_por_km:.02f}")
```

As "f-strings"  executam qualquer expressão em Python dentro de `{ }` em uma string, e, se após a expressão, houver o delimitador `:`, aplicam sobre o resultado a [mini-linguagem de formatação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax). No caso temos `:02f`, que significa "um número em ponto flutuante, com duas casas depois do ponto decimal, preenchidos com `0` se o número for redondo".

**sugestão 2**

Outra boa prática - sobretudo quando se lida com valores financeiros, é, em vez de usar números em ponto flutuante nativos, que tem limitações para representar alguns números decimais, e outras restrições de arredondamento, trabalhar o tempo todo com números decimais. Em Python, esses são um outro tipo numérico - a classe `decimal.Decimal` - nesse caso, após cada entrada de número, e após cada operação, o resultado é arredondado para o numero de casas desejado - e a impressão so vai ter o número de casas desejado (sendo que a apresentação final pode ser ajustada da mesma forma que a anterior, por exemplo, para incluir os "00" dos centavos após o ponto decimal se o número for redondo).

Tem duas dicas legais aí: a primeira é que a precisão padrão dos decimais é grande, então é importante alterar o contexto para ter só dois pontos decimais. A segunda, é que ninguem quer ficar digitando `decimal.Decimal(1)` para cada vez que for colocar um número no programa, então pode-se usar a sintaxe `from decimal import Decimal as D` para ter o nome `D` representando a classe `decimal.Decimal`

```
from decimal import Decimal as D, getcontext, setcontext
# As próximas 3 linhas limitam o contexto dos números a duas casas decimais
ctx = getcontext()
ctx.prec = 2
setcontext(ctx)

preco_por_litro = D('5.83')
km_rodados = D(22)
litros_abastecidos = D(1)
preco_por_km = preco_por_litro * litros_abastecidos / km_rodados
print(preco_por_km)
```

E isso vai imprimir `0.26`, só com duas casas - só que `.026` em vez do `0.27` - por conta do que escrevi acima, por que mudando-se o contexto, o resultado intermediário de cada operação é arredondado para apenas duas casas decimais - então o ".005" do ".265" se perde no caminho (mesmo que você ajuste a extratégia de arredondamento do contexto de decimais - que também é configurável - ela só vai ter efeito se a representação interna dos números for maior que duas casas decimais), e você usa a formatação de strings no momento da impressão, como no caso anterior.

**informações extras**

Python tem 3 funções de arredondamento para números em ponto flutuante - `math.floor`, `math.ceil`, que exigem a importação do módulo `math`,e a função `round` que é embutida (builtin). Essa útlima, além de somente arredondar um número para o inteiro mais próximo, como acontece na maior parte das outras linguagens, permite um segundo parâmetro, *opcional*, que diz o número de casas decimais desejadas. Você pode usar esse round, passando "2" no segundo parâmetro, quando for imprimir o resultado das suas contas, sem formatação de string, e etc - -mas tem que ter em mente que se tentar limitar o número em duas casas decimais em resultados intermediários de suas contas, o código estará sujeito as limitações que são parte de [como os números em ponto flutuante funcionam](https://floating-point-gui.de/) (esse link é o mesmo que o segundo acima) - inclusive, dependendo do número, e da forma de impressão, ele pode se "expandir" de novo para mais que duas casas decimais, mesmo com o uso do "round". Exemplo de uso: `print(round(preco_por_km), 2)`. As funções `math.ceil` e `math.floor` sempre vão arredondar para números inteiros.
Os números do tipo `decimal.Decimal`, mesmo se usados internamente com uma precisão maior, tem o método `quantize` que permite um arredondamento passando-se como parâmetro um número decimal `1.00` (para duas casas decimais). Ex.: `print(preco_por_km.quantize(D('1.00'))` - se o contexto tiver mais de duas casas vai imprimir `0.27`.  (lembre-se, com o `Decimal` você pode trabalhar com uma precisão interna ilimitada - apenas que operações com mais de algumas dezenas de milhares de dígitos vão começar a ficar realmente lentas)

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo. Sua explicação resolveu e muito o meu problema, sem falar que enriqueceu meu aprendizado. Mais uma vez muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Usa a função `round()`.

Ela recebe dois parâmentros (número a ser arredondado, quantidade de casas decimais). No seu caso basta colocar `round(0.265, 2)` que vai retornar `0.27`.

Cuidado com usar `,` ou `.`.

Comment: Muito obrigado, essa função acabou me ajudando a resolver o problema.

Comment: Se puder marcar como a resposta correta seria ótimo =D

Answer (score 2):

Olá, tudo bem? Sou muito novo no ramo da programação, mas, espero poder ajudar.

Segue abaixo um exemplo que arredondaria da maneira que você precisa:

```
preço=float(input('Qual o preço do combustível: R$'))

km=float(input('Quantos quilômetros são gastos por litro: '))

total= preço/km

print('{:.2f}'.format(total))
```

NOTE: `print('{:.2f}'.format(total))` Nessa linha de comando, coloco chaves e formato o que deve ser mostrado dentro delas. Coloco `.format(total)`...ele vai mostrar o total, porém, como coloquei `{:.2f}` eu digo ''Me mostre o resultado com apenas 2 pontos flutuantes'' ou seja, `{:.2f}` e ele faz o arredondamento do jeito que você quer. Fica 0.27

Comment: Somos 2 hehehe. Pensei nisso também, porem precisava arrendondar o número. O format é bom mas não arredonda para cima nesses casos.