# Biblioteca math

Tags: python, matemática

Galera uma dúvida.
Estou dando uma estudada na biblioteca math. Qual a diferença pratica entre: ceil, floor e trunc??

A idéia é tirar a parte flutuante do número.
Abraço!

Answer (score 3):

Embora esta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/580252/10301489) seja baseada em [Microsoft .net](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) ela está bem didática, traduzida via google translate:

> <strike>Siga estes links para obter as descrições do MSDN sobre:</strike>
>
> 1. **Math.Floor**, que arredonda para o infinito negativo.
> 2. **Math.Ceiling**, que  arredonda para o infinito positivo.
> 3. **Math.Truncate**, que arredonda para cima ou para baixo em direção a
>      zero.
> 4. **Math.Round**, que arredonda para o inteiro mais próximo ou para o
>      número especificado de casas decimais.
>
> <strike>Você pode especificar o comportamento se ele for exatamente
>   eqüidistante entre duas possibilidades, como arredondamento, de modo
>   que o dígito final seja par (" Round(2.5,MidpointRounding.ToEven)" se
>   tornando 2) ou que fique mais longe de zero ("
>   Round(2.5,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)" tornando-se 3).</strike>
>
> O diagrama e a tabela a seguir podem ajudar:
>
> ```
> -3        -2        -1         0         1         2         3
>  +--|------+---------+----|----+--|------+----|----+-------|-+
>     a                     b       c           d            e
>
>                        a=-2.7  b=-0.5  c=0.3  d=1.5  e=2.8
>                        ======  ======  =====  =====  =====
> Floor                    -3      -1      0      1      2
> Ceiling                  -2       0      1      2      3
> Truncate                 -2       0      0      1      2
> Round (ToEven)           -3       0      0      2      3
> Round (AwayFromZero)     -3      -1      0      2      3
> ```
>
> Note que Round é muito mais poderoso do que parece, simplesmente porque
>   pode arredondar para um número específico de casas decimais. Todos os
>   outros arredondam para zero decimais sempre. Por exemplo:
>
> ```
> n = 3.145;
> >     a = System.Math.Round (n, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven);       // 3.14
> >     b = System.Math.Round (n, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // 3.15
> ```
>
> <strike>Com as outras funções, você tem que usar o truque multiplicar /
>   dividir para obter o mesmo efeito:</strike>
>
> ```
> c = System.Math.Truncate (n * 100) / 100;                    // 3.14
> d = System.Math.Ceiling (n * 100) / 100;                     // 3.15
> ```

*Tachado foi adicionado para partes não aplicáveis em Python

Aconselho ler esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/357221/110782), mais precisamente na parte de **Informações extras**

Comment: Poderia coloca link de tirou a informação? +1

Comment: @MauryDeveloper claro! Foi no stackoverflow em inglês [Difference between Math.Floor() and Math.Truncate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14/difference-between-math-floor-and-math-truncate) filtrando as respostas, dá pra fazer um ótimo estudo

Comment: Que bom. Achei bastante boa sua resposta. E ainda com esse link me ajudará bastante. Obrigado.

Comment: "arredonda para o infinito" ficou uma tradução meio estranha, dá a impressão que o resultado vai dar infinito... "*towards*" seria algo como "em direção a", que é um jeito mais complicado de dizer que arredonda para um valor maior ou menor que o número atual ("em direção ao infinito positivo" quer dizer que o valor será maior que o atual). Enfim, acho que seria melhor indicar a [documentação do Python](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/math.html), em vez de traduzir outra só para riscar parte do texto. E lá o texto é melhor, ex: ceil - "Return the smallest integer greater than or equal to x"

Comment: @hkotsubo entendo, por isso mencionei via google translate, pois sempre tive dúvidas na hora da tradução,  acredito que muitas vezes é melhor entender e usar o conceito em inglês. Mas uma dúvida, como ficaria a tradução, voltada para programação, de ceil e floor?

Comment: Eu usaria o que está na documentação do Python. Ex: "ceil - retorna o menor inteiro que é maior ou igual a x". Ou seja, `ceil(2.5)` retorna `3`, pois 3 é o menor inteiro que é maior ou igual a 2.5 - essa definição ajuda a entender também porque `ceil(-2.5)` resulta em `-2` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Fábio, todas tratam-se de funções que retornam apenas a parte inteira.

- **trunc** = Retorna apenas a parte inteira do número, ignorando os decimais
- **ceil** = Retorna apenas a parte inteira do número, arredondando para cima
- **floor** = Retorna apenas a parte inteira do número, arredondado para baixo

Na prática, tendo como entrada o valor **1.9**:

- **trunc** = Retorna **1**, pois ignora a parte decimal
- **ceil** = Retorna **2**, pois arredondou para cima
- **floor** = Retorna **1**, pois arredondou para baixo

Código:

```
import math

teste = 1.9

print(math.trunc(teste))
print(math.floor(teste))
print(math.ceil(teste))
```

Answer (score 0):

Nesse código mostra os métodos trunc,ceil e o floor:

```py
import math    
  
print(math.floor(23.91));
print(math.ceil(23.91));
print(math.trunc(23.91));
```

No console mostra o resultado:
23,24,23

Floor: retorna o menor número inteiro dentre o número "x".

Ceil: retorna o menor número inteiro maior ou igual a "x"

Trunc: Remover as casas decimais do valor.

Mais informações:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/floor-ceil-function-python/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-35-truncate-in-python/